# How to keep Rally radio button field stay same size while resizing window

Tags: css, radio-button, rally, window-resize

In my current app I have a radio field that is sitting in the upper-left corner of the window.  I have given this component a class name of 'radio-buttons' and given the following css to the component:

```
.radio-buttons {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: dotted;
}
```

The border is dotted just so I can see the outline of the component.  Every time I resize the window, the radio button field shrinks small enough so that the buttons cannot be seen at all.  The dotted border can still be seen so I know the component is still in the app, it just shrinks majorly.  I tried adding:

```
position: fixed;
```

to the radio-buttons class, but this has not helped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  [hopefully this is a simple fix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I searched for my question outside of StackOverFlow and found the following link:

http://css.dzone.com/news/how-resize-extjs-panel-grid

This site answers the question 'how to resize a panel' instead of keeping the panel from resizing, but I stole the following line of code and put it in my 'radio-buttons' class:

```
position: absolute;
```

and now my radio button field doesn't resize itself on window resizing!
Basically all I had to do is change

```
position: fixed;
```

to

```
position: absolute;
```

Here's my final css class that keeps the radio button in place:

```
.radio-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can specify the minimum width and height for a class or ID. try something like the following:

```css
.radio-buttons {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: dotted;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

This will set the width and height to 20% of the window size, unless that is less than 50px.

Comment: That may be helpful for other components in the app, but this particular radio-button field needs to stay the same size at all times.